# Set font-size on <html> or <body>?

Tags: css, font-size

What is the best practice for setting the base font-size in your CSS file? Better to declare the font-size on the `<html>` element or the `<body>` element?

I'm using REM units (with px-based fallback for < IE9) and it seems better practice to do the following:

```
html { font-size: 100% }
body { font-size: 1rem }
```

...rather than:

```
body { font-size: 100% }
```

Reason: If you want to make a global change to the font-size in your media queries the latter method doesn't seem to work whereas the former does.

Comment: Despite the media queries topic, you may find useful [this other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905834/should-i-set-the-default-font-size-on-the-body-or-html-element).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would set the initial font-size on the "html" element to keep your root font size consistent across media queries.

Answer (score -2):

There is little point in declaring `font-size` on the `html` element unless you intend to make something in the `head` element visible as part of the page, which is very rare and normally a useless idea. Other than that, such a setting could have an effect only via inheritance to the `body` element, so why not set the size on `body` directly?

It is impossible to guess what your style sheet is supposed to do. Both alternatives lack any real effect except when used to override settings made in other style sheets. You should formulate your problem with media queries as a separate question, describing an actual problem, illustrated with code that demonstrates it.