# How can I set font size for my entire HTML webpage using CSS?

Tags: html, css, font-size

Hello I am a new beginner to CSS, and I wondered if anyone could help to advise how I could set the font size for my entire webpage?

The tutorials I've been looking at just show me how to set font size for each separate section.  I am using the same font-size for 99% of my page, so I don't want to have to code each and every single new paragraph, table row, cell, etc.

I'm already using a simple code for changing the font family for the ENTIRE page (see below), so I am assuming there is a simple code for the size that does the same.

```
    <style>
    *{font-family: Verdana;}
    </style>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your font family and size in the body tag, and with a few exceptions, all the elements in your page will inherit that size:

```
body{
   font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
   font-size: 12px
}
```

Optionally, you can set any of your elements to an `em` font-size:

```
p{
   font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

1 `em` is equal to the font-size of an element's parent, so in this case the `p` tag is one and a half times the size of the `div` tag. Since the `div` tag is 12px (inherited from body), the `p` tag is 18px:

```css
body{
   font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
   font-size: 12px
}

p{
   font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <p>I'm in a p tag, my font size is 18px</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size) in the same wildcard selector:

```
* { 
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

Keep in mind that the wildcard selector `*` carries the least [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity); any font sizes declared elsewhere will override this declaration.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! that seemed to have done the trick!

Comment: This resets the default font sizes of tags like h1...h5

Comment: @rogue_otter be warned that this will overwrite all elements' default `font-size`s, such as `<h1>` through `<h5>` tags.

Comment: @symlink you are right. my headings changed too. I do want a solution that applies to the whole page, unless I specifically designate a certain section with its own size. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. You can do this by using the HTML tag. Some might disagree with the location, but I like to have it here since it's on the root of the element. When you get more in depth you will start to likely use REM and EM units more and this seems to make more sense to me. But in reality you can put it on the asterisk, body, or HTML. Each of these uses the same CSS:

`font-size: XXpx;`.

```
HTML {
  font-size: XXpx;
}

body {
  font-size: XXpx;
}

* {
  font-size: XXpx;
}
```

[Here's a good link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905834/should-i-set-the-default-font-size-on-the-body-or-html-element) that might have some more advanced topics but has some good discussion

Best of luck on your development journey!

Comment: The wildcard selector overrides h1...h5 tags, unlike body or html

Comment: yup, that's right. That's why I recommended the HTML tag specifically, but wasn't sure if the OP wanted a larger wildcard font-size

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
  *{
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 24px; /* change size to what you need for you page */
  }
</style>
```